# What's the point of being able to declare an object but not instantiating it

Tags: java, oop, initialization, instantiation

For example:

```
Thread thread1 // would declare a thread variable named thread1
thread1 = new Thread() //would instantiate thread1.
```

Why wouldn't Java automatically instantiate it when the variable is declared? Is there a purpose to object variables that are not instantiated?

Comment: Why should Java automatically instantiate it when the variable is declared?

Comment: you can use declaration as global variable and then later point of time you can use it. mostly in PolyMorphism(where base class reference can refer to any of child class object)

Comment: Initialise it with what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to assign to the variable a reference to an instance that was created elsewhere, so it makes no sense to automatically create an instance.

In addition, there may be multiple constructors to choose from, and the compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

Further more, the type of the variable may be the type of an abstract class or an interface, for which you can't create an instance. You can only create an instance of concrete sub-classes or classes implementing the interface.

Answer (score 3):

> Why wouldn't Java automatically instantiate it when the variable is
>   declared? Is there a purpose to object variables that are not instantiated?

Java does initialise the instance/object variables to their default values. Default values for objects is null and for primitives their corresponding default values.

You can declare a variable and instantiate it only when required. This is a good memory saving technique in conditional code: instantiate/use the reference only in scenario where it is needed.

Comment: in which case it will initialize?? (normally if you declare and use you will get null pointer exception)

Comment: @Prashant Yep, that's the "default" value for an instance field object, sure "instantiate" might not be the right term though

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right, initialise the apt word and not instantiate.